# FQL to Get public event AND stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Im trying to get and events stream. More specifically the posts and comments about the particular event.  I can get the event with no problem.

```
SELECT eid,pic, name, start_time, location, ticket_uri, venue FROM event WHERE creator =
```

What I need are the comments/stream/posts underneath.
I've spent a few days on this with no luck.
Here is a sample page Im trying to get the info from:

https://www.facebook.com/events/336787446434356/

I want all the pics, vids comments etc..

Thank you

Comment: Did you get any help from the answer? You can accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following FQL to retrieve posts related to a particular event:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = {Event_Id} LIMIT 500
```

Similarly, you can perform the following multi-query to retrieve the comments:

```
SELECT text FROM comment WHERE post_id IN 
(SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = {Event_Id} LIMIT 500)
```

Replace the **{Event_Id}** with the Id of your Event.

Comment: Rahil, Do some events prevent you from viewing their streams?  Does my app need to be granted permission?  Just curious.  Thank you

Comment: If the event is public, you don't need ant permission. You just need a valid Access Token to view the stream. But if the event is not a public event, you might need a user_events or friends_events permission to view the event stream.